# Laravel API prevent multiple insert/update

Tags: php, laravel

I have a method for sending a notice on my `NoticeController`.

The issue was it cannot detect whether the api endpoint was called multiple times (such as double form submission from client side) or if the notice was already sent to the student. It causes duplicate records on the database, when I need it to only insert once.

```php
 public function sendStudentNotice(Request $request, Registrant $registrant){

        $validated = $request->validate([
            'type' => 'required|in:success,error,warning,info',
            'message' => 'required|string'
        ]);

        //This is inserting new record each call
        $registrant->enrollmentLogs()->create($validated);

        return response()->json(['message' => 'A notice has been sent successfully!']);
    }
```

It would be better if I can protect all `store` and `update` methods on my controller to prevent this kind of issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `->firstOrCreate([],[])` method instead of create, and it'll first check the database for a record for all the fields given in the first argument, and then if it doesn't find it one it'll create one along with the data in the second argument.

example for you:

```
 $registrant->enrollmentLogs()->firstOrCreate($validated, []);
```

Comment: This will not let the user to send the same message again. Like if the user needs to send the same message for tomorrow or after an hour.

Answer (score 0):

Make changes as per below

`$registrant->enrollmentLogs()->create($validated);` replace this line with below code

```
$registrant->enrollmentLogs()->firstOrCreate([
            'type' => $request->input('type'),
            'message' => $request->input('message')
    ], $request->only('type', 'message'));
```

Comment: This will not let the user to send the same message again. Like if the user needs to send the same message for tomorrow or after an hour.

Comment: @DarwinMarcelo add your client-side form code also in question so I can check.

Comment: The code related to client-side is really not important for this question. I have tried some of the solution, such as disabling the submit button after a post request. But if the user would somehow bypass the client-side "security", I want a backend protection so it wont duplicate the process and affect the database.

Comment: @DarwinMarcelo please check if any observer or event triggers on this API because insertion does not affect duplicate entry.